# Form errors are not displayed after validation - Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I have a form in simple HTML and does not use strut tags. When it goes through validation and on error the action does something like

```
      addFieldError( ""st_enroll.roll"", "Already taken" );
```

The problem is on error the user is directed back to the form as expected but the errors are not displayed. Is it because i am not using struts tags ?
My form content is like this

```
 <label>Student Roll:</label>    <input type="text" name="st_enroll.roll"/> <br>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: i have to say , you are asking lots of struts-2 basics , so i would recommend you to read  http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/home.html

Comment: Yeah. I am just waiting for my Struts in Action. Ill be getting it any day now. Ill probably polish up my basics with the link.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use     `<s:fielderror/>` in your jsp to show the errors. Put it where you want to display (probably at the top of page) and use `<s:textfield>` tag

- [Read the documentation on how to use field errors.](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/FieldError.html)
- [Read an Example About Field Error](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts/struts2.2.1/tags/fielderror_tag.html)